# Read a custom configuration XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have read a XAML file using XAMLReader which refer some custom assemblies. Reading a simple XAML file is easy as I can convert the file to stream and then call XAMLReader.Load().During Xaml load code throws exception for the custom assemblies in xmlns .Below is the code added in a WPF application:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(Filepath);
            string s = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
           var index = s.IndexOf("Canvas");
            s = s.Insert(index + 6, "xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"");
            var c = XamlReader.Parse(s) as Canvas;           
        }
```

and my XAML looks like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Canvas xmlns:IN_SE_BlendObjects_FactoryCast_Shapes_BasicShapes="clr-namespace:IN.SE.BlendObjects.FactoryCast.Shapes.BasicShapes;assembly=IN.SE.BlendObjects.FactoryCast" xmlns:IN_SE_BlendObjects_FactoryCast_Shapes_Extended_Shapes="clr-namespace:IN.SE.BlendObjects.FactoryCast.Shapes.Extended_Shapes;assembly=IN.SE.BlendObjects.FactoryCast" xmlns:IN_SE_BlendObjects_FactoryCast_Control_Animation="clr-namespace:IN.SE.BlendObjects.FactoryCast.Control.Animation;assembly=IN.SE.BlendObjects.FactoryCast" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
      <Canvas.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFFFFFFF" />
      </Canvas.Background>
      <IN_SE_BlendObjects_FactoryCast_Shapes_Extended_Shapes:FCastLinearGauge Canvas.Left="347.632293701172" Canvas.Top="215.769805908203" Width="328.600006103516" Height="131.440002441406" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" LabelText="" LabelFontFamily="Arial" LabelFontSize="12" IsLabelBold="False" IsLabelItalic="False" ShapeCornerStyle="Rounded" IsBackgroundVisible="True" BorderWidth="0" MajorScaleDivision="2" MinorScaleDivision="5" ScaleContainerType="Rectangle" IsLimitScaleVisible="True" ScalePrecision="1" MajorScaleHeight="15" MinorScaleHeight="8" ScaleValueFontFamily="Arial" ScaleValueSize="13" IsScaleValueBold="False" IsScaleValueItalic="False" IsValueVisible="True" ValueFontSize="12" IsValueBold="False" IsValueItalic="False" ValueTextAlignment="Center" Variable="Name:Variable1,Type:,DefaultValue:" MinEUValue="0" MinValue="0" MaxEUValue="100" MaxValue="100" HHLimitValue="80" HLimitValue="60" LLimitValue="40" LLLimitValue="20">
        <IN_SE_BlendObjects_FactoryCast_Shapes_Extended_Shapes:FCastLinearGauge.LabelColor>
          <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF000000" />
        </IN_SE_BlendObjects_FactoryCast_Shapes_Extended_Shapes:FCastLinearGauge.LabelColor>
        <IN_SE_BlendObjects_FactoryCast_Shapes_Extended_Shapes:FCastLinearGauge.BackGroundColor>
          <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" SpreadMethod="Pad" Opacity="1">
            <GradientStop Color="#FF095050" Offset="1" />
            <GradientStop Color="#FFA2B8BA" Offset="0.354999989271164" />
          </LinearGradientBrush>
        </IN_SE_BlendObjects_FactoryCast_Shapes_Extended_Shapes:FCastLinearGauge.BackGroundColor>    
      </IN_SE_BlendObjects_FactoryCast_Shapes_Extended_Shapes:FCastLinearGauge> 
    </Canvas>
```

Comment: What is the exception you are seeing? please provide the message and stack trace.

Comment: I am getting the below Exception:                                 {"'Cannot create unknown type '{clr-namespace:IN.SE.BlendObjects.FactoryCast.Shapes.Extended_Shapes;assembly=IN.SE.BlendObjects.FactoryCast}FCastLinearGauge'.' Line number '6' and line position '4'."}                                           and the stack trace is                                                   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)

Comment: Although that doesn't match the error message, but when you write `s.Insert(index + 6, "xmlns=...")`, don't you create a string like "Canvasxmlns=..."? Shouldn't it read `s.Insert(index + 6, " xmlns=...")` with a leading blank?

Comment: Clemens- what you say is correct in the original code i am using          .Insert(index + 6, " xmlns=...") with a space in starting . Due to formatting in the question you can't find the initial space.